# css chain selectors

Tags: html, css

both this structure comes in same page how to target this div  in css
only difference is ul class....

i wanted to give two different border colors yellow and pink color this div

[**http://jsfiddle.net/LWutU/5/**](http://jsfiddle.net/LWutU/5/)

**zpass-current**

```
<ul class="zpass-current zpass-homepage logo-med-whttxt clearfix">
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <div class="entitlement">
                <div id="box_go">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    <li>
</ul>
```

**zpass-header**

```
<ul class="zpass-header zpass-homepage logo-med-whttxt clearfix">
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <div class="entitlement">
                <div id="box_go">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, your question is unclear: which div do you want to target? And, can you edit the HTML? About your code, you have twice the same `id` (`#box_go`) this could cause trouble as `id` must be unique to a page.

Comment: IDs *must* be unique in a page. When doing a `getElementById(...)`, it will return *only* the first matched element with that ID.

Comment: I think those divs are in separate pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
.zpass-header .entitlement { border: 1px solid yellow; }
.zpass-current .entitlement { border:  10 px solid pink; }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i wanted css with respect to this id="box_go"

Comment: Then just exchange .entitlement with #box_go